# Solve Integral Equation using matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical

```
Line 227: f1 = @t v*w*cot((sqrt(v))*(t-t2) + acot((sqrt(u2/w))))/(rout - rb/2 - (t - t2)*(t - t2)*g*(sin(k))/2);

Line 228: f2 = @t x4t2d - quad(f1, t2, t2d);

Lin3 229: t2dapprox = t2 + 0.1;

Line 230: t2d = fsolve(f2, t2dapprox);
```

Matlab is giving errors: `Cant parse at v in 227. Parse error at x4t2d in 228`

P.S. All values are (supposed to be) scalars in 227

Comment: `f2 = @t x4t2d - quad(f1, t2, t2d);` isn't even valid Matlab code for defining an anonymous function. Where is this copied out? Show the actual code and provide a runnable example with input values.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare inline functions like this, you need to tell MatLab which letters are variable - by default it assumes x is a variable, but here you use v, w, t... and a bunch of others - declare this in your function

Comment: I don't know what the OP's code is, but it looks more like anonymous functions than inline functions.

Comment: @ Mauvai and @ horchler It turned out that x4t2d, which was calculated based on some input information was calculated wrongly due to noise in input. This made the equation wrong. Also I made the correction, f1 = @t v*w*cot((sqrt(v))*(t-t2) + acot((sqrt(u2/w))))./(rout - rb/2 - (t - t2).*(t - t2)*g*(sin(k))/2); - used ./ and .* . Now the equation works, I appreciate help.

Comment: One more thing, all the variable names in the f1 expression (except 't') denote some constant whose value has been calculated in the code preceding: f1 = @t v*w*cot((sqrt(v)......

Comment: If they're being calculated in the code then whether or not they're constants from then on, the code sees them as variables, and must be treated as such.